# jquery autocomplete with webservice,ajax and json doesn´t return values in the right way

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

i want to use the jquery autocomplete function. The data comes from a webservice who give back the data in json format. But the output in the associated texbox does not function. I got displayed the full json array.

Please give me a hint.

my WebService looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Zusammenfassungsbeschreibung für WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string customer(string queryParam)
    {



 string conStr=
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySql_classicmodels"].ConnectionString;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
        MySqlCommand readCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone   FROM customers where customerName like '%" + queryParam + "%'", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(readCommand);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(datatable);

        return DataTableToJSON(datatable);




    }

public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{
List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
    }
    list.Add(dict);
}
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return serializer.Serialize(list);
}


}


}
```

My ASP / JQuery Code looks like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#auto").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Webservice1.asmx/customer",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{ queryParam: "' + request.term + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value:item

                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })



</script>
```

My result is this:

```
[{"customerName":"Australian Collectors,  Co.","contactLastName":"Ferguson","contactFirstName":"Peter","phone":"03 9520 4555"},{"customerName":"Australian Gift Network, Co","contactLastName":"Calaghan","contactFirstName":"Ben","phone":"61-7-3844-6555"},{"customerName":"Australian Collectables, Ltd","contactLastName":"Clenahan","contactFirstName":"Sean","phone":"61-9-3844-6555"}]
```

What´s going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting whole object as a value. I believe that should be a string. Try:

```
return { value: item.customerName };
```

Comment: I have tried your hint, but it doesn´t work. Now the associated textbox doesn´t give anything back.